# How do you have a cell stay highlighted until you pop the view controller it transitions to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

Many apps have this effect where you tap the cell, it transitions to a new view controller, and then when you pop that view controller go to back to the cells, the cell you tapped to get there fades out only then. Basically, it only fades out when you return to the view controller, giving you a really nice visual queue as to which cell you tapped.

It's visible in Mail.app, for instance.

How do I do this? It seems I can only make it fade immediately or not at all.

Comment: That's the standard behavior of a `UITableView`. Perhaps you should show your code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @Doug Smith:  Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you have two view controllers, `ListViewController` (Table one) and `DetailViewController`.

- In ListViewController.h, add one param: `selectedIndexPath` (NSIndexPath type).
- In ListViewController.m -> `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, set its value to current indexPath

  selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
- Now when you tap back button from `DetailViewController` and come back to `ListViewController`, `viewWillAppear` method gets called from `ListViewController`.

ListViewController.m -> viewWillAppear

```
if (selectedIndexPath != nil) {

   // 1. get the cell using cellForRowAtIndexPath method from selectedIndexPath position
   // 2. now you can set cell.contentView.alpha = 0
   // 3. write an animation block which will set alpha to 1 in particular time block, let say 1 sec.

    [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.0f];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:1.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut // change option as per your requirement
                     animations:^{
                         [cell.contentView setAlpha:1.0f];
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
}
```

Update the animation block as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.